# sample program with test cases for regression testing

Tags: testing, testcase, regression-testing

I am working on a research of test case prioritization. And I need some sample program with set of test cases. I found some program [here](http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~gupta/teaching/206-12/project.html).

But I need some more. If anyone have any resources like that please share with me. It will be help!

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not actually a question, you're looking for resources.  Use the search tool and/or use Google.

Answer (score 0):

Incremental Scenario Testing Tool

Description
IST supports the test teams in managing their complexity by adaptively selecting and prioritizing the test cases according to the past test results. ISTT guides the testers through a test session with high-level test scenarios generated on the fly.

Features
IST is an innovative hybrid of scripted and exploratory testing to automate the test planning for flexible, adaptable and efficient test sessions.
Find as many bugs as possible by generating prioritized scenarios based on the analysis of previous test runs.
Involving developers allows focusing test resources on areas of the software which are naturally error-prone.
Install it on your own server or try it for free on the demo server at https://istt.symphonyteleca.com/ ! (request trial access through the contact mailing list, which is linked from the login page)

for download or more information please visit http://sourceforge.net/projects/istt/

TestCube

Description:
Jataka Testcube is a Web-based test case management tool designed to integrate & track enterprise-wide Test Cases.

for download or more information please visit http://www.jatakasource.org/testcube/#1